# Is there UI to manage ASP.NET Identity users/roles compatible with ASP.NET 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

**I'm using:**

- VS2015u2
- ASP.NET 5
- MVC 6

**I'm looking for some UI to manage users/roles.**

Some things I've tried:

- Identity Manager - https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager
  I guess it's still not compatible with the latest asp changes.

Comment: Are you looking for a tag or statement that allows you to hide elements depending on your role? Or just to add, edit and delete roles / permissions?

Comment: Just add/edit/delete users/roles.

Comment: Have you found something?

Comment: Nothing yet. Please update if you find something.

Comment: Seems everybody make proprietary solutions for this :) 
I'll try to have a look at IdentityManager (which is for Identity 2) - is it possible to port it to Identity 3/.Net Core...

Comment: Any findings on this? :)

Comment: Anyone find something for .NET Core 2.0?

Comment: I am also looking for something for MVC, @johnny .NET Core 2.1 has the Identity UI which is in preview mode , but looks promising: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/03/02/aspnetcore-2-1-identity-ui/

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/mguinness/IdentityManager and see if that suits your needs.

Comment: For ASP.NET Core Identity, following repo may be helpful - https://github.com/mguinness/IdentityManagerUI

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I tested the ASP.NET Web Application template with Individual Authentication and it worked fine with ASP.NET 5.

It is a Razor Pages Library, that you can scaffold if you need to edit the code as detailed here in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

This is the relevant part:

[image: How to scaffold Identity on ASP.NET 5.0]

The code in this case is Razor Pages instead of MVC, but you can have both in the same project as far as I understand, and migrating from Razor Pages to MVC should be fairly simple as stated in this GitHub discussion: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1825#issuecomment-396342979

Answer (score -3):

Please check out **ASP.NET MVC 5 Security And Creating User Role**
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score -5):

If you want get all of roles and users with UI to manage asp.net Identity.

Try to make new blank asp.net MVC project. Make sure do not click Individual User Account. Then go to Package Manager Console and hit following query on console.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Version 2.2.0-alpha1
```

This package contains an asp.net MVC application which shows you how to use the features in asp.net Identity. Also compatible with asp.net. You should check default role and users once you connect database with ApplicationDbContext.